# Двойная аутентификация python requests,почему не редиректит?

Tags: python, парсер

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте zelenka.guru.Отправляю пост запрос на сайт с верными данными ,но вместо редиректа на страничку с подтверждением почты, возвращает страницу с регистрацией. Ещё responce.status_code=200,а не 303 как это бывает с авторизацией руками. Я ожидал что в responce.headers.get будет ссылка но её там нету.

Вот что возвращает:

```
<bound method Mapping.get of {'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Wed, 16 Nov 2022 11:58:39 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '10362', 'Connection': 'close', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Set-Cookie': 'xf_is_mobile=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, xf_session=ea8f1295d99d50e81cca40d25141eb24; path=/; secure; HttpOnly', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 16 Nov 2022 11:58:39 GMT', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://lzt.market', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-ajax-referer', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'}>
200
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie xf_session=ea8f1295d99d50e81cca40d25141eb24 for zelenka.guru/>]>
```

Вот код:

```
import requests
link='https://zelenka.guru/login/login'
headers=({
    'cookie': 'sfwefwe=8c16c5c96cae292ce5f22066a6159834; _ga=GA1.1.287412218.1668510398; _ym_uid=1668510400369105409; _ym_d=1668510400; _ym_isad=2; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; xf_session=133de5157b7f9c4e4924609a7bd71ad7; xf_is_mobile=1; _ga_J7RS527GFK=GS1.1.1668528171.2.1.1668530185.0.0.0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
})

data=({
    'login': 'login',
    'password': 'password',
})
s=requests.Session()
  

responce=s.post(url=link,headers=headers,data=data)

print(responce.headers.get())
print(responce.status_code)
print(s.cookies)
print(responce.history)
```

Comment: Если я правильно ошибаюсь. responce.headers.get() - должен выглядеть так.

Comment: Так покажите, что теперь печатает, после исправления

Comment: data не хватает ключей для корректного пост-запроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуется больше data ключей

```
data=({
'login': 'login',
'password': 'password',
'remember': '1',
'stopfuckingbrute1337': '1',
'cookie_check': '1',
'_xfToken': None
})
```